# Ant - Generate .class files even if compiler errors

Tags: ant, build

How to successfully build using Ant, if the code has compilation errors?

If I have 3 .java files and 1 has a compilation error, is there anything that can make my build successful and can give me the remaining 2 .class files?

```
<target name="build" description="Compiles the Source code" depends="Directory.check">
    <echo>Compilation Starts</echo>
    <javac failonerror="false" includeantruntime="false" destdir="${build.dir}"
        deprecation="false" optimize="true" executable="${exec.dir}">
        <compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked"/>
        <compilerarg value="-Xlint:deprecation"/>
        <src path="${src.dir}"/>
        <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
    </javac>
    <echo>Compilation Ends</echo>
</target>
```

Comment: If i have 3 java files and 1 has compilation error. Is there any thing that can make my build successful and can give me rest  2 .class files.

Comment: ahh sorry, your code was not visible to me at first. can you explain why you want/need this? (am just curious)

Comment: In our product there are huge number of Java files and some are having compilation, as they don't interfere in day to day functioning of product so they are kept as it is in packages. I do not want to manually remove those classes as they might be required in future. So the basic idea was to create standalone build.xml which can create .class files and jar as soon as code changes.

Comment: any idea @hoijui ..how we can do this?

Comment: you should use a CVS (like git), which allows you to easily restore files after they have been deleted, and then delete the files. anyway, you want to fail the build if some files fail compilation,but not with others, so you woudl have ot maintain a list of known bad files.. it is all a very bad and ugly solution, you should not ry to get it working that way.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate though src files using for from ant-contrib.
Pass the file name to javac in includes attribute with the src basedir as srcdir.

```
<target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source ">
    <for param="file">
        <path>
            <fileset dir="${src}" includes="**/*.java" excludes="**/Sanity/*.java"/>
        </path>
        <sequential>
            <local name="program"/>
            <basename property="program" file="@{file}" suffix=".java"/>
            <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src}" debug="on" includes="**/${program}.java"
            excludes="**/Sanity/*.java" destdir="${build}" failonerror="false" 
            verbose="true">
                <compilerarg value="-Xbootclasspath/p:${toString:lib.path.ref} -Xlint:deprecation -Xlint:unchecked"/>
            </javac>
      </sequential>
    </for>
</target>
```